# SQLite Returns Incorrect Drawable

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

After the most recent Android Studio update, suddenly all of my app's drawable images are incorrect!

I have an SQLite database where I store a couple of static drawable images. Initially I was storing the int R.drawable.myDrawable,but after learning that drawable resource id's can change at anytime on Android, I am instead storing the drawable name (I'll notate that part in the code snippet)

Everything was working fine up until recently and no changes have been made.

Upon further debugging I found that when naming my database the images are all off. If i set the db name to null the images are correct (but obviously no data can be stored or persisted if the SQLite database name is null)

I am stumped please help...

Here is where I name/un-name my database. For testing purposes I usually set the database name to null as a quick hack so I won't have to uninstall the entire application everytime

```
public FFDBHelper(Context context){
    super(context,FFDBSchema.DB_NAME,null,FFDBSchema.DB_VERSION);
    //super(context,null,null,FFDBSchema.DB_VERSION);

}
```

Here is the code for the drawable references (Note that this particular table is stored to the SQLite database during its initial inception. The values here should not change except for squad1details && squad2details

```
     private static void writeModeChooserTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
       db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + FFDBSchema.Tables.MODE_CHOOSER_TABLE
            + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.MODE_ID_COL +" TEXT,"
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.TABLE_ID_COL + " TEXT,"

            + FFDBSchema.Colz.GAME_MODE_TYPE_COL + " TEXT,"
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.GAME_MODE_PIC_COL + " TEXT,"
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.SQUAD_DETAILS_1_COL + " TEXT,"
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.SQUAD_DETAILS_2_COL + " TEXT);");

    Resources res = Funx.getInstance().getAppContext().getResources();
    String preseasonPic = res.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.pre_back);
    String onlinePic = 
    res.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.ffredbackcrop);
    String godPic = res.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.god_mode_back);

    modeChooserInserter(db,AllSchema.Funx_Schema.FF_PRE_SEASON,
            preseasonPic,null,null,null);

    modeChooserInserter(db,AllSchema.Funx_Schema.FF_ONLINE,
            onlinePic,null,null,null);

     modeChooserInserter(db,AllSchema.Funx_Schema.FF_GOD_MODE,
            godPic,null,null,
            null);
   }
```

Here is where the data is being called...

```
public void setModeChooserArrays(String mType, String picName,String mDetails1, String mDetails2) {
    if (theModePics.size() < 3) {
        theModeTypes.add(mType);

        int resId = Funx.getInstance().getAppContext().getResources().getIdentifier(
                picName, "drawable", "com.my.package_name");

        theModePics.add(resId);

        theSquad1Details.add(mDetails1);
        theSquad2Details.add(mDetails2);
    }
}
```

and where I bind the pics

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
    ImageView tierPackImage = cardView.findViewById(R.id.tierPackImage);

    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(cardView.getContext(), aModePics.get(position));
    tierPackImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: When you set name of the db to `null` you create an in-memory db. I suggest you extract the db file out of the emulator/device and examine it. If it is not very hard, uninstall the app so the db is deleted and rerun to recreate and repopulate the db.

Comment: At first glance it all seems normal. I need to do another comb over. I tried testing this on a different device and everything works fine...